# Python 2.7 convert special characters into utf-8 byes

Tags: python, python-2.7, url, special-characters

I have strings that I need to replace into an URL for accessing different JSON files. My problem is that some strings have special characters and I need only these as UTF-8 bytes, so I can properly find the JSON tables.

An example:

```
# I have this string
a = 'code - Brasilândia'

#in the JSON url it appears as
'code%20-%20Brasil%C3%A2ndia'
```

I managed to get the spaces converted right using `urllib.quote()`, but it does not convert the special characters as I need them.

```
print(urllib.quote('code - Brasilândia))
'code%20-%20Brasil%83ndia'
```

When I substitute this in the URL, I cannot reach the JSON table.
I managed to make this work using u before the string, `u'code - Brasilândia'`, but this did not solve my issue, because the string will ultimately be a user input, and will need to be constantly changed.
I have tried several methods, but I could not get the result I need.

I'm specifically using python 2.7 for this project, and I cannot change it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try decoding the string as UTF-8, and if it fails, assume that it's Latin-1, or whichever 8-bit encoding you expect.

```py
try:
    yourstring.decode('utf-8')
except UnicodeDecodeError:
    yourstring = yourstring.decode('latin-1').encode('utf-8')
print(urllib.quote(yourstring))
```

... provided you can establish the correct encoding; 0x83 seems to correspond to **â** only in some fairly obscure legacy encodings like code pages 437 and 850 (and those are the *least* obscure). See also https://tripleee.github.io/8bit/#83
(disclosure: the linked site is mine).

Demo: https://ideone.com/fjX15c

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. 
Your idea almost worked. I tried:
`a = "code - Brasilândia"`
`print(urllib.quote(a.decode('latin-1').encode('utf-8')))`

and I got `code%20-%20Brasil%C2%83ndia`
I'm guessing that my problem might be that Latin-1 isn't the right one. I will try others.

Comment: See update now; the site went down just as I was about to update this answer.

Comment: As an aside, this is one of the areas where upgrading to Python 3 would bring substantial relief.

Comment: I definitely agree about Python 3, but unfortunately this project requires python 2.7 for the time being

Comment: Thank you very much!!!
You're right about the legacy encodings. Using cp437 made it work! I would never have found it alone, never heard about it.

Comment: The problem then is how can you guess which encoding the user uses if they can pass in arbitrary input.